# sendmail NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): CentOS 7

Tags: sendmail, centos7

So I run the command:

`service sendmail start`

And this is the line of error I am getting:

`NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 1246: Xmailarchive: local socket name /var/run/f1.sock unsafe: Permission denied`

The socket has permissions: srwxr-xr-x and is owned by root.

The socket is also being used by a mailarchiver script in /etc/init.d:

    `#!/bin/sh
    #
    # mailarchive   This shell script takes care of starting and stopping
    #               mailarchive for sendmail.
    #
    # chkconfig: 2345 75 35
    # description: mailarchive archives all mail passing through sendmail
    # processname: mailarchive
    RETVAL=0`

```
start() {
        echo "Starting mailarchive"
        rm -f /var/run/f1.sock
        /usr/local/software/mailarchive/mailarchive -p local:/var/run/f1.sock &
}

stop() {
    # Stop daemon
        echo "Stopping Mailarchive"
        killall mailarchive
        rm -f /var/run/f1.sock
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
  start
    ;;

  stop)
  stop
    ;;

  restart)
    stop
    start
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
esac
```

So I'm wondering what the problem is. Can sendmail not use the socket or are the permissions wrong?

Comment: We can't see the permissions. They weren't included in your question!

Comment: oops, must have been deleted when I was editting. I keep hitting enter accidentally. The permissions are: srwxr-xr-x and is owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that all that I needed to do was turn off selinux :\